# Too many prisma connections in my NestJS code

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I am working on a NestJS project. All of a sudden, I started to face this error/warning:
`warn(prisma-client) There are already 10 instances of Prisma Client actively running.`. I am not sure when it started to surface. As a result, one other microservice written in NestJS too cannot connect to the same PostgreSQL server (yes I am using the same server for development, to make things easier).

I did my research. I am instantiating the Prisma client as per [the recommended way](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma). My understanding is this is supposed to instantiate a global prisma client, as [Prisma recommends](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices).

I commented two lines of code in `main.ts` and I no longer see the warning:

```
...
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(4000);

  // const webhooksApp = await NestFactory.create(WebhooksModule);
  // await webhooksApp.listen(4001);

  const prismaService = app.get(PrismaService);
  await prismaService.enableShutdownHooks(app);
...
```

The commented code originally was written to expose the API routes under the `WebhooksModule` on port `4001` in addition to the entire app being hosted on port `4000`.

Now as per my understanding, I think that at max, only two instances of `PrismaClient` should have been there. My questions are:

1. How are there 10 active instances of Prisma Client actively running?
2. Is my understanding incomplete/flawed? If yes, then please correct me.